# Gradient Background-image on an existing Background Image

Tags: css, transparent, linear-gradients

Is it possible to make a part of image gradient on an existing background?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPCrY.jpg]

Comment: and how I make this by CSS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The result as in the example picture you added can be achieved by using 2 containers, one with a background image, the other (which lies on top of the first) uses a CSS gradient background, where one of the gradient colors has an alpha of 0 (i.e. is transparent).

For more info on CSS gradients see: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients

to make a gradient that is transparent on one side, use rgba color, for example:

```
#grad1 {
    height: 200px; width:500px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,1), rgba(255,0,0,0)); 
}
```

The a in rgba stands for alpha, it is the transparency an has a value between 1(opaque) and 0(transparent)

Comment: It’s working with color gradient, not with image, I need two layer transparent image background. It is not transparent, but white color gradient